# Engineering term for the "coherence between drawings, products and BOM(Bill of materials)?"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, terminology, american-english, technical

As the title says, is there any engineering term meaning 'coherence(or consistency) between technical drawings, products and BOM(Bill of Materials)?'

This concept is used in manufacturing to say that the technical drawings, products and BOM should match.

It is also used in electrical engineering to say the schematics, PCB and BOM(or parts list) should match.

Is there any English word for that? 
I wanna say simply like "**(that term) is satisfied" or "Check the **" or "** is checked"

Comment: We often don't have words for vanishingly rare situations. But I guess you could dig up and dust off *synergy*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider *synchronize* (the -z- spelling is used because the relevant documentation tends to be heavily biased towards AmE). Also, *sync* and *in-sync* (or *synchronization* if you're looking for a noun).

> **synchronize** *verb*
>   1.3 (no object) Agree with something else.
>   ‘their version failed to synchronize with the police view’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synchronize)

In hardware and software development, the term is used in the context you describe - having various documents match each other.

Here are a couple of representative examples:

- Whether you're transferring a captured design to a new PCB for the first time, or making changes to an existing design on either the schematic or PCB side, some way of keeping the two sides in-sync is required. Altium Designer provides a powerful design synchronization feature that delivers an effective solution to the problem of keeping the design synchronized, allowing the designer to keep their focus on the creative aspects of the design process.
  [- altium.com](http://www.altium.com/documentation/16.1/display/ADES/((Design+Synchronization))_AD)
- Models quickly become out of sync with the code, and there is nothing wrong with that. You must then make the decision to synchronize the models if doing so adds value to your project or to simply discard them because the investment to update the models won't be recouped by the value of having done so (there's negative payback).
  [- agilemodeling.com](http://www.agilemodeling.com/practices.htm)

Comment: Awesome! This is what I've been looking for. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

schematics

> This plural is a common use in fields where illustration and documentation ordinarily requires many related documents. The schematics typically include many schematic diagrams--perhaps a separate diagram for each layer or subsystem--just as the blueprints for a building typically include many floor plans and detailed drawings, and the elevations for a stage set typically include many illustrations and color renderings. – StoneyB Dec 25 '15 at 23:13 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76964/why-is-schematics-used-in-its-plural-form-for-a-single-item

Alternatively, some might say *all the specs* have been met